# Sqlalchemy query returns Decimal object

Tags: casting, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, sqldatatypes

I have the following model:

```
  172  class ReportRecord(db.Model):                                                                                                                                                                                
  173     __tablename__ = 'tb_report_record'                                                                                                                                                                         174                                                                                                                                                                                                                175     id = db.Column(Integer, primary_key=True)                                                                                                                                                                
  176     report_id = db.Column(ForeignKey('tb_rua_report.id'), index=True)                                                                                                                                        
  177     source_ip = db.Column(String(100, 'utf8_bin'))                                                                                                                                                           
  178     count = db.Column(Integer)                                                                                                                                                                               
  179     disposition = db.Column(String(10, 'utf8_bin'))                                                                                                                                                          
  180     header_from = db.Column(String(100, 'utf8_bin'))                                                                                                                                                         
  181     spf_domain = db.Column(String(100, 'utf8_bin'))                                                                                                                                                          
  182     spf_result = db.Column(String(10, 'utf8_bin'))                                                                                                                                                           
  183     dkim_domain = db.Column(String(100, 'utf8_bin'))                                                                                                                                                         
  184     dkim_result = db.Column(String(10, 'utf8_bin'))                                                                                                                                                          
  185     isActive = db.Column(Integer, nullable=False, server_default=text("'1'"))                                                                                                                                  186     created_by = db.Column(String(100), nullable=False, server_default=text("'System'"))                                                                                                                     
  187     created_dt = db.Column(DateTime, nullable=False)                                                                                                                                                         
  188     last_modified_by = db.Column(String(100), nullable=False, server_default=text("'System'"))                                                                                                               
  189     last_modified_dt = db.Column(DateTime, server_default=text("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"))                                                                                                                         
  190                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  191     report = db.relationship('RuaReport', backref=db.backref("record"))
```

When I am issuing the following query from `flasksqlalchemy`

```
ReportRecord.query.filter(or_(ReportRecord.spf_result=="pass", ReportRecord.dkim_result=="pass")).with_entities(func.sum(ReportRecord.count).label('total_passed')).all()
```

I get the following output:

`[(Decimal('930'),)]`

Now the value that I get is correct, but I cannot `jsonify` it directly. Doing a `int(Decimal('930'))` does give me the desired result but what is the default way to get this data converted in the right format?

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:
Include this in your imports:

```
from sqlalchemy import func
```

then:

```
total_passed = db.session.query(func.sum(ReportRecord.count)).scalar()
```

This returns **930** instead of **[(Decimal('930'),)]**

Read more about [.scalar()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.scalar)

Answer (score 3):

How about converting the decimal while querying it?

Try `int(func.sum(ReportRecord.count).label('total_passed'))`

try enforcing your db to cast values into integer should solve your problem

I cannot check but there is a cast function which might be useful as well

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import cast
cast(func.sum(ReportRecord.count).label('total_passed'),sqlalchemy.Integer)
```